# Using ES6 `import` with CSS/HTML files in Meteor project: bug or feature?

Tags: html, css, meteor, import, ecmascript-6

I am currently learning Meteor and I found out something that intrigued me.

I can load HTML and CSS assets from a JS file using the import statement.

```
import '../imports/hello/myapp.html';
import '../imports/hello/myapp.css';
import * as myApp from '../imports/hello/myapp.js';
```

This was a surprise to me so I ran to google but could not find this behavior documented in the specification for ES6 `import` or in Meteor's Docs.

So my questions are:

- Can I rely on this behavior to build my apps?
- Will my app will break when Meteor gets around to fix it -- if it's a bug --?

**Notes**

- I am using Meteor v1.3, not sure if this works also with previous versions.
- You can download the app to see this behavior from [Github](https://github.com/pgpbpadilla/meteor-playground/tree/so-es6-meteor-import-bounty)

Comment: Why are you importing CSS and HTML into JavaScript files? You do not need to do this in Meteor.

Comment: Granted, there are other ways of achieving the same. The question remains, is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Where are you, Meteor community? Come and take this bounty please!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After going through the implementation of the built files for my app
I found out why this works.

**HTML**

Files are read from the file system and their contents added to the global Template object, e.g.,

```
== myapp.html ==

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> hello}}
</body>
```

results in the following JS code:

```
Template.body.addContent((function () {                                                                       
  var view = this;                                                                                          
  return [
     HTML.Raw("<h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>\n\n  "),      
     Spacebars.include(view.lookupTemplate("hello"))
  ];
}));
```

Which is wrapped in a function with the name of the file as it's key:

```
"myapp.html": function (require, exports, module) {

     Template.body.addContent((function () {                                                                       
          var view = this;                                                                                          
          return [
             HTML.Raw("<h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>\n\n  "),   
             Spacebars.include(view.lookupTemplate("hello"))]; 
     })); 

     Meteor.startup(Template.body.renderToDocument);                                                              

     Template.__checkName("hello");                                                                               
     Template["hello"] = new Template("Template.hello", (
         function () {                                            
           var view = this;                                                                                         
           return [
               HTML.Raw("<button>Click Me</button>\n  "), 
               HTML.P("You've pressed the button ", 
                      Blaze.View("lookup:counter", 
                      function () {
                        return Spacebars.mustache(view.lookup("counter"));                                                   
                      }), " times.")
          ];                                                                                         
     }));                                                                                                         

},
```

So all of our HTML is now pure JS code which will be included by using `require` like any other module.

**CSS**

The files are also read from the file system and their contents are embedded also in JS functions, e.g.

```
== myapp.css ==

/* CSS declarations go here */

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Gets transformed into:

```
"myapp.css": ["meteor/modules", function (require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = require("meteor/modules").addStyles("/* CSS declarations go here */\n\nbody {\n    background-color: lightblue;\n}\n");

}]
```

So all of our CSS is also now a JS module that's again imported later on by using `require`.

**Conclusion**

All files are in one way or another converted to JS modules that follow similar rules for inclusion as AMD/CommonJS modules.
They will be included/bundled if another module refers to them. And since all of them are transformed to JS code
there's no magic behind the deceitful syntax:

```
import '../imports/hello/myapp.html';
import '../imports/hello/myapp.css';
```

They both are transpiled to their equivalent forms with `require` once the assets have been transformed to JS modules.

Whereas the approach of placing static assets in the `imports` directory is not mentioned in the official documentation,
this way of importing static assets works.

This seems to be at the core of how Meteor works so I'd bet this functionality is going to be there for a long while.

I don't know if to call this a feature maybe a more appropriate description is unexpected consequence but that would
only be true from the user's perspective, I assume the people who wrote the code understood this would happen and perhaps even
designed it purposely this way.

Comment: just out of curiosity , where did you find these `compiled` HTML/CSS code?

Comment: `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/app.js`

Comment: you can drop the `..` in your '../imports' apparently you can use `/imports/...` so you don't need to track how many levels up to go.

Comment: how to adress files imported like this ?
```import '../imports/hello/myapp.html';```
```import mytemplate ??? '../imports/hello/myapp.html';```

Answer (score 2):

One of the features in Meteor 1.3 is lazy-loading where you place your files in the `/imports` folder and will not be evaluated eagerly.

Quote from Meteor Guide:

> To fully use the module system and ensure that our code only runs when
>   we ask it to, we recommend that all of your application code should be
>   placed inside the imports/ directory. This means that the Meteor build
>   system will only bundle and include that file if it is referenced from
>   another file using an import.

So you can lazy load your css files by importing them from the `/imports` folder. I would say it's a feature.

Comment: This does not explain why we're able to import static assets like CSS and HTML files.

Comment: Lazy loading, css modules, jss, etc. This is why you need to import css in your js files. I'm not sure what is the use case for html imports.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 export and import functionally are available in Meteor 1.3. You should not be importing HTML and CSS files if you are using Blaze, the current default templating enginge. The import/export functionality is there, but you may be using the wrong approach for building your views.

Comment: I know now that this is not the standard approach. The question remains: bug or feature?

Comment: Neither? You can import and export. What is the bug?

Comment: The reason I asked the question is that I never expected to be able to include HTML and CSS files by using the `import` keyword. And like the question says I haven't found any docs that explain this behavior yet. I like the fact that I can explicitly import any asset instead of having to place them in special places and then rely on the magic loading mechanism and that's why I would like to know if this behavior will be there always or it will be disabled at some point in the future.

Comment: ES6 import and export are only for javascript files. That has nothing to do with Meteor.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I thought, it should only work for JS files. The question is: Why does it work for HTML and CSS files too?

Comment: What are you actually doing with your HTML import statements? It seems to have no effect the way you wrote it in your question.

Comment: If you comment out the line where the HTML is imported then the markup in that file will not be loaded in the page. You can try if for yourself, the code is available at the link provided.