# Meteor doesn't serve all HTML files in a directory

Tags: javascript, meteor

While working through Meteor **TODO app** tutorial, I ran into a problem at step 10, **Publish and Subscribe**.

The problem is that this code in **imports/ui/task.js** no longer works:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './task.html'; // <= fails in the browser
```

The directory **imports/ui** contains:

```
body.html   body.js     task.html   task.js
```

I can `import './body.html';` fine, but not `import './task.html';`, or any other HTML file for that matter -- e.g. I tried to rename **task.html** into **flask.html** and import it accordingly, and it still failed the same way.

Trying to debug it in Chrome I found that it sees a different set of files:

[image: Chrome debug snapshot]

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105068/using-es6-import-with-css-html-files-in-meteor-project-bug-or-feature) I was able to find the generated **app.js**, which has

```
Template.body.addContent((function() {
```

but no (expected?)

```
Template.task.addContent
```

So my question is why Meteor build is not picking up **task.html**?

NOTE: I have just updated Meteor to 1.8.0.2. Could that be a new bug in that release?

**UPDATE**

I restarted from scratch with the same tutorial and has made it through step 10 without problems.

I then ran a diff on the two projects. So far I was unable to find the *root* cause for this problem, however *a* cause was visible in

**.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/app.js**

as the attached diff shows:
[image: diff of new vs original]

The original (on the right) is missing the section generated from **task.html**

The question is still why? Are there any compile logs I can look at?

Comment: Did you created the project using `meteor create` or did you cloned it from gihtub?

Comment: It was created using `meteor create`, I was just following the TODO app tutorial. I also tried to do `meteor reset` without any success.

Comment: Ok I will try to reproduce

Comment: Can you describe what "fails in the browser" ? can you give us the error message ? From what I see it's likely that you have an error in the task.html file, but it's difficult to help without further information

Comment: My experience is that sometimes when Blaze encounters an error, it will just generate an empty (or missing) file. So this is likely a syntax error in task.html. Can you edit your question with the contents of that file?

Comment: Here's the **task.html** file:
`
<template name="task">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}} {{#if private}}private{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

    {{#if isOwner}}
      <button class="toggle-private">
        {{#if private}}
          Private
        {{#else}}
          Public
        {{/if}}
      </button>
    {{/if}}
    <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong> - {{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
`
Sorry it doesn't format well in comments.

Comment: @victor, the error in the browser (without the stack trace) is
**Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './task.html'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, @victor and @fred-stark were right on the money. It was a syntax error in the Blaze template!

```
<template name="task">
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}} {{#if private}}private{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>

    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

    {{#if isOwner}}
      <button class="toggle-private">
        {{#if private}}
          Private
        {{#else}} // <= should be {{else}} !
          Public
        {{/if}}
      </button>
    {{/if}}
    <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong> - {{text}}</span>
  </li>
</template>
```

I normally try to type it all myself when working on tutorials, instead of copy-paste. So, here I mistyped, subconsiously assuming the syntax for `else` would be the same as for `if`. Wrong!

Still it would be nice if there was some indication from the compiler during the build process.

Comment: Depending on meteor versions, some errors are displayed in the navigator or the terminal. I was about to redirect you to github to leave an issue open, but it's already open here : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/10433